# Docker - How to run a package installed during the build?

Tags: docker

I am trying to replicate something I do from the CLI in a docker image.
I install an npm package globally and just try to run it.

`npm` is successfully installed, but the CMD fails with `mup: command not found`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#...

# Install mup
RUN npm install mup -g

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "mup ${*}"]
```

Comment: Please run your container with entrypoint set to bash and find out where is mup located. Then update your CMD accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying a user in your Docker container so commands inside the container run as the root user.

The default global install location for `mup` is `/usr/local/bin/mup`.  The default `PATH` environment variable of the root user in Ubuntu 18.04 does not contain `/usr/local/bin`:

```
root@localhost:/# whoami
root
root@localhost:/# echo $PATH
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:
```

You could create a user that would have `/usr/local/bin` in their `PATH`, or adjust the root user's `PATH` to include `/usr/local/bin`, or use the absolute path, `/usr/local/bin/mup`, in your Dockerfile.